# General template problem

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, book-design

I need to achieve the following formatting. Is that possible?

[image: TOC]

Can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the document class you are using, but most classes that support chapters have the commands `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`, which support this sort of thing automatically.  For help on how to format the contents list itself, you should look at the [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package, or check the [tocloft](/questions/tagged/tocloft) tag on the site for examples of its use.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Disclaimer}
It's not my fault.
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
Thanks, Mom and Dad.
\chapter{Abstract}
A short summary
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
Intro
\chapter*{Objectives}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Objectives}
Objectives
\chapter{Background}
\section{History}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I already found `a different solution`. If you want I can post mine as well but yours is much cleaner.

Comment: @salamis It's up to you, but the solution I've posted (other than using a different documentclass) is pretty much "best practice", I think.